# SharePoint 2013 - detect how many pages are referencing my document

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Is there any way in SP 2013 to see how many (or which) publishing pages are making reference to a specific PDF document coming from Site Collection Documents?

Answer (score 0):

You need a site analyzer or link checker. I would suggest A1 link checker, http://www.microsystools.com/products/website-analyzer/

Comment: You can write as much code as this post can handle. As long as you cover the basics, I would (and most people) upvote you for a great, descriptive, well-thought-out answer.